# How to configure correctly my IDE to find import packages?

Tags: firebase, intellij-idea, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

It is simple to reproduce in IntelliJ IDEA CE 2017.2:

1. Create a New Flutter Project (you name it).
2. Try Build → Rebuild Project
   Error: Specify SDK en the Project Structure dialog.
   Fixed by selecting Android API 16 Platform (Java version 1.8.0_112).
3. Try again Build → Rebuild Project
   Error: `Android Source Generator: [project_name] AndroidManifest.xml file not found`.
   Fixed by going to File → Project Structure → Modules, selecting project_name_android → Android and adding `/app/src/main` after `/android` on each field... Manifest file: Resources directory: Assets directory and Native libs directory.
4. Try again Build → Rebuild Project
   Error: `android-apt-compiler: .... types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value ...`.
   Fixed by deleting `layoutDirection|` (do not forget delete one | bar).
5. Try again Build → Rebuild Project
   Error: `Android Pre Dex: [flutter.jar] Failed to load dx.jar`... and 10 more error messages
   Fixed by downgrading SDK to version 25.
6. Try again Build → Rebuild Project
   Everything is OK.
   Now add package dependencies in pub `spec.yaml`

   Consider this as my `pubspec.yaml`:

   ```
   name: myproject
   dependencies:
     flutter:
       sdk: flutter
     firebase_database: 0.1.0
     firebase_storage: 0.0.6
     async_loader: 0.1.0
     path_provider: 0.2.1+1

   dev_dependencies:
     flutter_test:
       sdk: flutter

   flutter:
     uses-material-design: true
   ```
7. Try again Build → Rebuild Project
   Error `java: package io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database does not exist` and 5 more errors

It runs on Emulator and Device. But it seems something wrong or missing in setting up my IDE properties?

Comment: "Create a New Flutter Project (you name it)." do you use `flutter create` for creating?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the command line for creating a new flutter project:

```
flutter create project_name
```

This should fix all issues for you.

- Use `flutter create --help` for all the options you have for creating a new project including organisation, iOS and android language etc.
- Use the green arrow to run your application. There should be no errors there.

Comment: @Rainer_Wittman, your answer does not answer the question.  If you look at the end: "I have to say: It run on Emulator and Device. But it seems something wrong or missing in setting up my IDE properties?".  So, I know about "flutter create..." and "green arrow...".  My question is **not** about it, Question is: "How configure correctly my IDE to find import packages in Flutter?"

Answer (score 0):

> Try again Build->Rebuild Project Error java: package
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database does not exist and 5 more errors

Try to run `flutter pub get` after adding new dependencies to the pubspec file.